# Show the relationship between the trace and the number of 4-cycles

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trace, spectral-graph-theory

Let $G$ be a k-regular graph.  Show the exact relationship between $tr(A^4)$ and the number of 4-cycles in $G$.

I understand how $tr(A^4)$ tells us the total number of closed paths of length 4 in $G$, but that doesn't seem useful since that includes, among other things, 4-cycles along one edge.

Answer (score 4):

There are exactly $|v|^2=k^2$ options for closed walks beginning with $v$ and ending with $v$ that are not $4$-cycles.  So, each entry of the diagonal of $A^4$ will have an extra $k^2$ walks that are not $4$-cycles, which means that if $a_i$ is the number of $4$-cycles beginning and ending with vertex $i$, we can rewrite the $i^\text{th}$ diagonal entry as $a_i+k^2$.  So, $$\operatorname{tr}(A^4)=\sum_{i=1}^{|G|}\left(a_i+k^2\right)=|G|k^2+\sum_{i=1}^{|G|}a_i$$
We've counted every $4$-cycle exactly $4$ times in $\sum_{i=1}^{|G|}a_i$, so letting $X$ be the total number of $4$-cycles in $G$, we get $$\operatorname{tr}(A^4)=|G|k^2+4X$$

Comment: Oh I see. I couldn't think of how to count the number of paths that "doubled back." So we get that there are $k^2$ options by considering the 4 vertices you go along on the path, right? $k$ for the first one, $k$ for the second, 1 for the third (repeat of second) and we end at the starting vertex.

Comment: Actually, I'm having some doubts now:

There are $k \cdot k$ options for closed walks of the form $\left( v_0,v_1,v_0,v_2,v_0 \right)$ and $k(k-1)$ closed walks of the form $ \left( v_0,v_1,v_2,v_1,v_0 \right) $ with $v_0$ and $v_2$ distinct.  Bringing my total number of closed walks that are not 4-cycles to $2k^2-k$.

Comment: Moreover, we've counted each cycle 8 times (twice at each vertex of the cycle), so I think we should actually get $$\operatorname{tr}(A^4)=|G|k(2k-1)+8X$$

Comment: @AGiftbox Nice - I didn't see the second kind, $(v_0,v_1,v_2,v_1,v_0)$.  I think you're right.